# if/else not working jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to change text in one div depending on the text in another div.

Here is the code:

```
$("#pricebtn").click(function () {
if ($('#titl01').html == "Services") {
  $('#titl01').html("Prices");
}
else {
  $('#titl01').html("No Prices");
}
```

Mainly what I need is - if the text in the div #titl01 is "Services" I need it to be changed to "Prices" otherwise change to "No Prices".

The problem with the code is that it changes text to "No Prices" even if the text in the div #titl01 is "Services"....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.html()` is a *function* you can call, not a plain property

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation of `html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and see how to use it. Flagging this post as off-topic as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.html() is a function not a property in jQuery.**

```
$("#pricebtn").click(function () {
  if ($('#titl01').html() == "Services") {
  $('#titl01').html("Prices");
}
else {
  $('#titl01').html("No Prices");
}
```